# Como instalar o java 8 no ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: java, react-native, ubuntu, ambiente

Antes de mais nada,sei que parece uma pergunta um tanto boba,porem sou um "usuario" Windows, tenho o dual boot em minha maquina.Admiro muito o unix, e pretendo migrar para ele de vez.

Estava usando o ubuntu 18 mas formatei a maquina e instalei ubuntu 19.
Nisso instalei o nosso querido java, mas eu instalei nas pressas e sem querer intalei o java 11.
Tentei remover ele e instalar o java 8 mas não tive sucesso.

Quando dei comando `java -version`: obtive.

```
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu219.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu219.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Sendo que quero desenvolver applicações com o react-native e preciso usar o java 8 ao inves do mais atual.

Como faço para o instalar?
 Alguem ja passou por isso aqui?
Quando tento instalar o java8  , como reposta sou informado que ele não esta mais no repositio.

Tentei [esse tutorial](https://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/openjdk-8-no-ubuntu-19-04/) mas nada.

Comment: Primeiro, remova o openjdk na versão 11.
`sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk*`

Instale manualmente. Baixe no site da Oracle a versão 8, extraia, coloque em /usr/lib/jvm e seja feliz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Se você utilizou o `apt` para instalar:

O primeiro passo é desinstalar as versões antigas.

```
sudo apt remove openjdk-11*
```

Isso fará com que o apt procure qualquer pacote que contenha "openjdk-11" instalado, e aí, o remove. Depois, basta usar

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Talvez você precise baixar o pacote openjdk-8-jre também.

---

## Se você instalou manualmente:

Remova o openjdk na versão 11.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk*
```

Em seguida, [baixe no site da Oracle o JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (necessário fazer login, mas é coisa rápida). Extraia o seu conteúdo em `/usr/lib/jvm/` e você já tem o JDK 8 em sua máquina.

Em ambas as versões é preciso que você exporte suas variáveis de ambiente do Java.

Para isso, edite o arquivo `/etc/profile`:

`$ sudo nano /etc/profile`

Adicione as linhas:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/nome-da-pasta-do-seu-jdk/ 
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH export PATH JAVA_HOME
CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar 
CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH 
export  JAVA_HOME  PATH  CLASSPATH
```

Reinicie o computador e cheque se tudo está certo usando o comando

`java -version`

---

[Referência](https://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/instalar-java-no-linux-veja-como-fazer-isso-manualmente/)